# How to access duration of audio file in android using Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

```
 iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");     
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");        
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);

}


private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
        String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
        String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, track +"\n"+artist+"--"+album, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
};
```

I am new in android please help me someone.
This code is work properly but I can't access the duration and path of the mp3 file. Please help me.